# Apache and php7.0-fpm – sporadically error 500

Tags: php, debian, apache-2.4, php-fpm, 500-error

I am running an office server based on Debian (for developing websites based on TYPO3) and have changed from mod_fcgid to PHP FPM – just to have two PHP versions available in an easy way...

Now I am working on a project/vhost with PHP 7.0 running and get sporadically error 500. When I refresh the same page / or do the same action it works – so it's really annoying since I cannot find any solution for that.

I am using the default php7.0-fpm config.

My vhost config looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost  192.168.2.10:80>
    ServerName mdo.ka.dev
    ServerAlias mdo.ka.dev

    DocumentRoot /var/www/git_websites/MDO
    SuexecUserGroup myuser mygroup

    ServerAdmin info@myemail

    UseCanonicalName Off
  DirectoryIndex index.htm index.html index.php

  AddType application/x-httpd-fastphp7---mdo .php
  Action application/x-httpd-fastphp7---mdo /php7-fcgi---mdo
  Alias /php7-fcgi---mdo /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi---mdo
  FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi---mdo -socket /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock -idle-timeout 900 -pass-header Authorization

    <Directory /var/www/git_websites/MDO>
        AllowOverride FileInfo
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And I am getting the folling errors:

```
[Mon Apr 10 10:02:37.341218 2017] [fastcgi:error] [pid 20539]  (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 192.168.2.54:60604] FastCGI: comm with server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi---mdo" aborted: read failed, referer: http://mdo.ka.dev/kontakt/distributoren/
[Mon Apr 10 10:02:37.341271 2017] [fastcgi:error] [pid 20539] [client 192.168.2.54:60604] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi---mdo", referer: http://mdo.ka.dev/kontakt/distributoren/
```

I don't understand where the problem is. I am getting the same error 500 / the sam log message when I stop the PHP FPM service. So I thought "he" can't connect to the FPM server. But when I increase the processes in the config or switch from dynamic to static mode nothing changes. I am the only user using this webserver on that machine – so there cannot be too few processes.

I also turned off the Zend Opcode and the APCU module. Also nothing changed.

Hope someone can help – it's a annoying to work with these errors.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the solution: https://github.com/gplessis/dotdeb-php/issues/124
Install a newer version of libpcre3.